# Nginx as "Gateway" usage

Tags: nginx, debian

### What is my problem?

I have one IP address and multiple domains with subdomains.
All domains and subdomains points to my IP to Debian machine with nginx version: nginx/1.10.3.
I have other servers in my local network which I want use.

### What I want?

Let's say that I have these domains:

- example.com
- example.me
- private.example.me

I want point **example.com** to local IP **10.0.0.3** and I want it for port **80** and **443**

Next I want point **example.me** to local IP **10.0.0.4** and this is where main problem I want use port **22 - SSH** over it and ports **80** and **443**

And the last (maybe worst) I want point **private.example.me** to local IP **10.0.0.5** on ports **22 - SSH, 80, 443, 5900 - VNC, ...**

### What I know so far?

I have many configs in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*** like this:

```
root@Gateway:/# nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com 

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass              http://10.0.0.3:80/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header        Host            example.com;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass              http://10.0.0.3:443/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header        Host            example.com;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

That works because it is HTTP traffic, but it won't work for TCP/UDP traffic like SSH, VNC, VPN, ...

How to make this work?

Comment: nginx is not capable of doing what you want. This won't work.

Comment: Only way you can make this work is to have a separate public IP address for all your private addresses, and then perform 1:1 NAT to private addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to work. nginx can act as an HTTP proxy, but not for SSH or VNC. Also, at the very least for SSH (and I believe VNC as well), you can't separate traffic at all based on domain name as there is no information in the traffic that would make this possible.

Comment: Ok, and if so, what do you recommend me? How to do that? (nginx was my only hope)

Comment: You can't do this. It's as simple as that.

Comment: and what about stream function in nginx? It works for me on port 5900 but I don't know how to separate traffic based on domain name...

Comment: Again: This is not possible. HTTP has a header for this specific purpose, but most other protocols don't and they can't split traffic based on domain name.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only have one vnc and ssh server behind your proxy, you can use ip forwarding on your gateway host to redirect traffic to those services. not with nginx but with iptables.